# How Publish Module On Drupal.org

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have Create Some Useful Module For Drupal 7 and I want to publish that on drupal.org marketplace . I haven't found any helpful documentation to publish this item .  Can you help me to publish them .

**My R&D Links**

https://www.drupal.org/node/1108980

Comment: Please Add Comment Before Down vote

Comment: SO is not a "Step-by-step" guide, secondly, this isn't even a coding / programming question. - Also, completely optional whether a user wants to comment or not.

Comment: have ever publish  drupal module ???

Comment: No, but even if I had, it wouldn't change anything, it's not a question for SO.

Comment: please help me yaar .. Where i will get help

Comment: Commenting: show your code. If your question is not attached to some code or some coding concept, it's not a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: How Can i publish A module Code ?? i want to upload it on drupal site

Comment: Do please head over to [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finaly I have Got It . HopeFully It It Help Other Drupal Lover Also

**Initial Step :**
[Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1047190) to Config Druple With Git

**Create Project**
[Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-module) To Create project

> After Save goto the `Your-Project>Version control` and follow the git
>
> code

```
mkdir kasper_test

cd kasper_test

git init

git checkout -b 7.x-1.x

echo "name = Kasper test" > kasper_test.info

git add kasper_test.info

git commit -m "Initial commit."

git remote add origin kasper@git.drupal.org:sandbox/kasper/2581077.git

git push origin 7.x-1.x
```